# Why is my mousehook inside dll unable to recognize simple BOOL?

Tags: c++, winapi, autoit

```
#pragma data_seg(".shared")  // ".shared" is defined in exports.def to allow  
HWND        m_hHwndMouse = 0;
HHOOK        m_hHookMouse = 0;
BOOL hover = true;
#pragma data_seg()
```

this section is managed with .def file

```
EXPORTS
    SetValuesMouse
    MouseProc

SECTIONS
    .shared READ WRITE SHARED
```

I am directing this dll(adding values) + trying to change the BOOL hover = true; by changing this value trough autoit dll call

DllCall(".\simplemousehook.dll", "int", "SetValuesMouse", "hwnd", $main, "hwnd", $hhMouse[0], "BOOL", 0)

this simply makes the

```
HWND        m_hHwndMouse = 0;
HHOOK        m_hHookMouse = 0;
```

from the shared section changed in the function SetValuesMouse

```
void WINAPI SetValuesMouse(HWND hWnd, HHOOK hk, BOOL ho)
{
    m_hHwndMouse = hWnd;
    m_hHookMouse = hk;
    hover = ho;
}
```

Ok, so now my mouse hook inside DLL knows where to send messages(m_HWNDMOuse)

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseProc( int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    wParm = AU3_WM_MOUSEMOVE;
        PostMessage(m_hHwndMouse, wParm,(WPARAM)( (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT*) lParam )->hwnd,     LPARAM(fromp));
```

This works perfectly fine and my gui(which is hHwndMouse ) normally receives the message from the dll, so obviously i am able to change it  trough setvaluesmouse function

BUT...

if i do this

```
if (hover = 1)
{
.. do something here
}
```

and prior to that i change the BOOL hover to 0 trough the function SetValuesMouse the dll ignores that hover is 0 and "does something here"...

Why is it unable to read the bool properly and ignore the ...do something here...?

I know i am probably making totally stupid mistake here but i can't help it but to ask for help.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing an `=` in the `if` condition, it should be `if (hover == 1)`.

Comment: See my comment for an example of why you should go a step further than spoon feeding a quick-fix. Your answer does not help with comprehension or prevent further mistakes in the same guise.

Comment: If he is doing so much with the mousehook etc I guess he knows basics of C language, I am just pointing out a simple oversight.

Comment: The problem is that lately i am totally into autoit and i didnt use c for long time and in autoit comparison for equalty is = and not ==, my mind totally switched and i simply made idiotic mistake. There is nothing about spoonfeeding that i need. Naveen made perfect answer that i needed.

Comment: There's a pretty long round-trip time for posting a question here and getting a meaningful answer compared to simply taking a step back and grabbing tea. I assume that by the time they've posted here, they're at least fairly stumped. In a case like this, this leads to believe they've misunderstood the semantics and don't need just a quick send-off. The subject matter (mousehook) is pretty irrelevant. I won't assume they know what they're doing unless they're implementing a wide-column store in C++ :P

Answer (score 1):

One = sign in C means assignment, when you incorrectly perform that if-check, you're actually mutating the value of hover and triggering the event unexpectedly.

== is the equality operator in C.